# The difference between "so far", "by now", "before" or "before now" in the Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, time-words

Can I use this adeverbs of time in order to convey my experience which I've got at the moment of speaking? I mean:

> 1. I've done it many times before now.
> 2. I've done it many times by now.
> 3. I've done it many times before.
> 4. I've done it many times so far.

Are they equal and have the same meaning?

Maybe "so far" has some kind of negative implication?

> 1. I haven't heard this legend so far.
> 2. He hasn't done it so far.

Comment: Including the word ***now*** in #1 strikes me as being "unusual" phrasing for most contexts. And #4 also seems non-idiomatic for most contexts, because ***so far*** is normally used to imply ***not much** so far, **but much more to come***. Perhaps it's a personal thing, but I would rarely if ever include ***by*** in #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are really situational and preference related but lets break them down:

1. I've done it many times before now - This I would NOT use. 'before now' is not good english.
2. I've done it many times by now - As this is I would NOT use either. Maybe try "By now, I have done it many times" - Still not a great option
3. I've done it many times before. - This one is not bad. It can be left as is.
4. I've done it many times so far. - This is OK. Really I think what makes these sound weird is 'many times' - I would say "I have done it a bunch so far" or "I have done this a lot".

"So Far" refers to time. It basically means 'NOW' - I havent heard this legend so far - really does not sound right. Maybe try "I havent heard this legend yet"

He hasn't done it so far - This sounds ok but depends on the context in which it is used